# 'Database Error: Unable to connect to the database:Could not connect to MySQL' in Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am using joomla 1.5, and my site was running fine, but suddenly couple of days back I got the error **Database Error: Unable to connect to the database:Could not connect to MySQL**

Its not always, the error is coming. Sometimes the error is coming, and sometimes not. If I have wrong database connection values, then why, is the site coming perfect sometimes. I double checked my database connection values, and are completely fine.

Try http://www.scholarsmarket.com/beta/top-ranked-students this link. Refresh this couple of times. You will get the problem

I am stuck with this error. Can't get out of this.

Comment: Check this -> http://www.joomplaza.com/tutorials/400-joomla-16-unable-to-connect-to-the-database-could-not-connect-to-mysql.html

Comment: Does Joomla uses connection pooling? Or perhaps the server has reached the max. no. of connections?

Comment: If that is the problem, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It a very common issue to tell exact reason, I think you should start from asking your hosting support about any limitations e.g. Database connections?

then take a look at the logs and statistics - probably you site suddenly got too much visitors at that time?

Answer (score 1):

If this error seems to pop up 'randomly' it's usually because either persistent connections are used (or another reason why the connection goes into sleep mode for some time). Persistent connections are generally not a good idea on medium- to high-traffic sites, since it clogs up your database with 'sleeping' connections. Once those connections hit the maximum connection account for your database user, the MySQL server will reject any new connections and throw the error you are seeing.

So, in order to fix this problem, make sure your db config is not set to use persistent connections. You can also verify if this is the problem by running this query on your database (given that you have the proper permissions to do so):

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```